# Issue in making appear all database table field names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code which i use in order to make appear all the names of a table of a database.

It used to work... but suddenly it won't make appear anything..
Could you please take a look?
I'm working with SQL.

```
$section = "SELECT * FROM forma";
$res = odbc_exec($connection, $section) or die(odbc_error());   
    $firstrow = false;
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)){
    if (!$firstrow) {
        foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
            echo "<label> " . $column . "</label>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='data[]' value='" . $column . "' /><br/><br/>"; 
        }
$firstrow = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why downvote?
I mean, i know you have the right to downvote, but why?

Comment: well, forma is the database table..
I want to show the database field names..

Comment: The SQL bit in your PHP-looking script is very trivial and is *highly* unlikely to break "suddenly". You might want to try to remember and then tell us what might happen between the last time it worked and the first time it stopped working. And also you might want to add a tag related to the language of the posted snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly nasty way of retrieving the column names for a table. What it is doing is reading all the data in the table, ignoring the result set and only using it for the column names. What is happening however is that the table is empty and so nothing is being returned at all.

You need to amend the query to look at the meta data rather than the table itself. You will need to rework it. This SQL will retrieve the column names for that table for you...

```
Select Columns.Name
  From Sys.Columns
 Where Object_Name(Columns.Object_id) = 'forma'
 Order By Columns.Column_Id;
```

After that you will need to rejig your code to take advantage of it.